# Considering definitions as equalities, what would happen if you continually substituted a word’s definition?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, automata

I’ve had this question for several years now but have next to no programming experience, nor good connections to anybody who does. So I decided to see if stack exchange had an answer.

The idea is to make a program that takes some linguistic, grammatically correct set of words (such as a sentence or phrase), substitutes every word for its definition as stated in the Webster dictionary, makes necessary changes as to keep it grammatically correct and meaningfully equivalent to the first one, and then repeat for this new set of words. What would happen? Would the sentence grow infinitely long? Would it go into some repeating loop? Would it go on forever, never repeating and never growing?

I would think it grows to be infinitely long, because every definition will have more words than the amount it’s defining (one, typically). But I’m still interested in what kinds of sentences it would churn out or if there are certain patterns for certain words or types of words.

I’m not necessarily asking for anybody to write the program, but if anybody does take up the challenge I do suspect the step of making the expanded sentence “grammatically correct and meaningfully equivalent” would be very difficult and I would not judge if you omitted this step.

How would this work? What would happen?

(as a side note, because I’m not very familiar with programming and computer science, I’m not confident in my choice of tags and I apologize if they’re more or less nonsense)

Comment: "substitutes every word for its definition". Do you mean "substitutes every word *with* its definition"?

Comment: Please give a few examples. For example, how will you change a pronoun such as "she" or "me"? A proposition such as "by" or "with"?

Comment: `I have` `past tense and past participle of have` `what is stated in the following phrase, clause, or discourse` `an interrogative expression often used to test knowledge` `used as a function word to indicate duration of time or extent of space` `more than two but fewer than many` `[plural] the period of about 3651/4 solar days required for one revolution of the earth around the sun` `by this time` <- make any sense to you?

Comment: (Reading that reminds me of when someone explained a Chinese poem by writing the English definition below each character. Their point was to show how it was impossible to directly translate into English, how half the meaning was implicit, and that's why English translations of the poem were so varied and failed to capture the essence)

Comment: @JohnL. Yes that is what I meant, I suppose I wasn't as clear as I could've been

Comment: @JohnL. In the case of she, the definition reads "a word used to reference a specific woman", or something similar, so it would be replaced with "in reference to the woman", so that it keeps tense and grammar rules, as well as specifying the subject it's centered on

Comment: @user253751 that does sound really similar, and that may be what this problem exposes, that much of English is implicit and contextual rather than 1:1 with its definitions as we'd like to think. English just isn't a precise or accurate language, admittedly. Also unfortunately no, your example does not make sense to me. I was concerned with how replacing "connecting" words like articles and propositions would work.

Comment: @Joseph_Kopp consider only "year" which is a noun and therefore easy to replace. Consider a few levels deep. "The amount of continued forward development of objective reality required for circular movement of the giant amount of solid mineral material on which we live around the giant amount of the substance consisting primarily of 1 big subatomic thing with positive electric charge, 1 small subatomic thing with negative electric charge, and 0 things with neutral electric charge." Does that make sense?

Comment: @user253751 in that case it did make sense, all though how much sense the new sentence makes isn't really what I was concerned with, although it is interesting. I was more so wondering on how one would maintain grammatical correctness in the program as well as if any phrases or words would create patterns.